# Is "the worst is yet to come" a future form for inanimate objects?

Tags: future, will-be-going, present-progressive

I hope the answers to this question will benefit anyone who studies English. 
I would like to understand the purpose of this future form in English:

> *something + is/are + to + verb.*

At school we were taught: *"I will do something"*. At university the following structures were studied: *"I am going to do something / I am doing something at 5:00 PM."*.
These forms seem to be quite enough to talk about the future. My question is about this example:

> *"The worst is yet to come."*

Why can't we say "The worst is *going to* come yet"? I usually see this structure applied to inanimate objects, so is that its purpose?  Is this construct used when we want to talk about the future of inanimate objects?

Comment: The *"yet to"* form isn't quite the same. It means that something hasn't happened now, but will happen in the future. If you say *"the sun will keep rising"*, it means that the sun will rise tomorrow, the day after, the day after that ... But *"the sun has yet to keep rising"* doesn't make any sense, because *"yet"* means it didn't happen before, while *"keep"* means that it did.

Comment: How about the headline "President Obama is to visit Cuba"?  Same structure, not an inanimate object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's worth noting to begin with, that in a way English has no future tense.*

Its verbs don't have future tense as do those of many other languages, and so all our ways of talking about the future are with combinations of verbs that are either infinitive or in other tenses.

## Will/Shall Future

The form you say you learnt in school uses a modal (*will* or *shall*) with a bare infinitive; "I will describe other future tense forms in this post"†

## Other Modals for the Future

We can use other modal verbs to change attitude or belief: "I might explain it well" refers to the future, but unlike "I will explain it well" it offers a future possibility with less conviction than *will*.

Sometimes it's not clearly present or future; does "I can stop writing" refer to the present (I have the ability to stop writing right now) or to a possible future? Really, it's both as one entails the other. (If I have the ability to do something, then I might in the future; if I might do something in the future, then I have the ability to do it).

## Going to Future

The *going to* form uses a present tense expression to indicate a future outcome.

Consider the present tense phrase "I am going to the shops". While it describes my present action that moves me through space, there is an entailed future outcome of my being at the shops. Now consider, "I am going to the shops to buy some food". Again this is a present tense statement that moves me through space, but we have more information about the future outcome. Now consider, "I am going to buy some food". Here we've lost the spatial movement, but kept the temporal movement to the future.

## Copula-Gerund Future

We can also just use the present tense, and have other statements supply the information that places us in the future. Your example of "I am doing something at 5:00 PM" is an example of that; "I am doing something" is present tense, but the additional "…at 5:00pm" indicates a future time-frame.

## Simple-Present for the Future

This also goes for the simple present: "my aunt arrives" is present, but "my aunt arrives tomorrow" makes it work in a future time-frame.

## Point of Commencement Future

A variant of this is to combine the present with an expression indicating that we are presently at the point when something is about to happen, which hence must be in the immediate future. "She is about to leave", "He's on the verge of going nuts", "I'm just coming to describing the 'worse is yet to come' form."

## Copula-To Future

The *is to* form uses the present to state a future the present is pregnant with. It's often used for plans "President Obama is to visit Cuba" as in one of the comments above means there is a plan now, for such a visit. It is also used to indicate events in the future that are consequent on conditions now. "Economy to improve" suggests not only will the economy be better in the future, but it will be so because of how things are now. (The *is* being dropped as is common with headline styles).

Your "the worse is yet to come" example is a case of this; it says things will get worse, but does so based on how things are now.

Note that we might say "the worse was yet to come" as a future-of-the-past sense even if nothing at the time would have made "the worse" inevitable. People tend to talk about the past as if the way the unfolded was destined and inevitable, even if they don't believe in kismet.

It's also worth noting that "The worse is to come yet" is logically as sensible, but "is yet to" is idiomatic.

> Why can't we say "The worst is going to come yet"?

The word *yet* means "still, at the present point in time". When we add it to "The worse is to come" it emphasises the **now** of that to show that because it is **now** still to come, it is therefore in the future.

"The worse is going to come yet" puts the *yet* on the future side of the "going to", and *yet* being about now does not belong in the future.‡

However, "The worse is not going to come yet" works, because it implies a further future (when "the worse" does come), so *yet* is still referring to a point in time "now" prior to a referred-to future.

---

*The hedge of "in a way" there is because depends on just what we mean by *tense*. Sometimes (particularly in teaching contexts) we include aspects as part of tenses, and sometimes we don't. Sometimes we include all constructions that affect time reference, sometimes only morphological changes. In the last case, we would understand English as having only a past and a present (or perhaps, non-past) tense. These different meanings of *tense* have different value in different cases, but ironically the meaning in which there is no future tense is the most useful for examining how the future tense works.

†There are some who would say that I should use "I shall describe…" above, preferring *shall* for the first person and *will* for the others and then reversing that to indicate strong determination or an obligation. Most people though tend to just use them interchangeably, with *will* being more commonly used. Strictly following the "I shall, you will" rule can work well in formal registers, but by the same token seem stuffy in less formal registers.

‡It's different with "the worse will be yet to come" which refers to the future-of-the-future because while that *yet* is in the future, it's still in an earlier time-frame than the *to come* talks about.

Comment: In many situations, the verb’s simple present now gets obligatorily replaced with the right inflection of *be* following by the verb’s *-ing* version. Not for the present-as-future, but in many other places where in almost all other European languages, the simple present tense is used. “What are you doing?” “I’m commenting on Jon’s post.”

Comment: @tchrist an argument for saying that English doesn't have a past and a present tense, but rather a past and a not-past tense.